# how can I extract specific objects in nested array with JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

```
arr = [
{
    "_id": "6271fd40fe5c58d4cbd3a72f",
    "index": 0,
    "guid": "60f843d2-1b6b-4536-b421-e5df1c4ab735",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$2,534.11",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 27,
    "eyeColor": "brown",
    "name": "Miranda Nguyen",
    "gender": "male",
    "company": "ZENTIA",
    "email": "mirandanguyen@zentia.com",
    "phone": "+1 (833) 466-3207",
    "address": "198 Dank Court, Hartsville/Hartley, Indiana, 8416",
    "about": "Consectetur proident anim do commodo ipsum. Elit consectetur irure dolore voluptate. Enim aute voluptate et qui do. Eu pariatur laboris labore esse enim reprehenderit mollit ullamco fugiat. Laborum sunt veniam consectetur laboris cupidatat. Lorem tempor occaecat labore ut et eiusmod amet.\r\n",
    "registered": "2021-06-16T11:50:54 -09:00"
},
{
    "_id": "6271fd40e30856d15651c60c",
    "index": 1,
    "guid": "ee647592-0647-4ad5-96b1-eb6c06a32dbd",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$2,636.22",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 35,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "name": "Florence Flynn",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "ELENTRIX",
    "email": "florenceflynn@elentrix.com",
    "phone": "+1 (901) 525-3731",
    "address": "246 Billings Place, Brandermill, Guam, 5037",
    "about": "Sint non dolore cupidatat voluptate laboris adipisicing eu quis. Laboris nostrud qui dolor cillum dolor nulla sint culpa est reprehenderit sint ipsum nisi excepteur. Qui cupidatat sint do aliquip ut. Officia est aliquip fugiat ex enim do sunt consequat.\r\n",
    "registered": "2014-12-10T08:44:47 -09:00"
},
{
    "_id": "6271fd404394e16d79143873",
    "index": 2,
    "guid": "3d3890ff-8241-4a2b-a361-789e0298817a",
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$1,047.32",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 25,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": "Debbie Pratt",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "OPTIQUE",
    "email": "debbiepratt@optique.com",
    "phone": "+1 (831) 537-3188",
    "address": "737 Quentin Street, Calpine, Louisiana, 9102",
    "about": "Officia nisi labore mollit cupidatat exercitation commodo duis adipisicing officia amet laborum. Nulla qui commodo aliqua reprehenderit dolore cupidatat esse ea pariatur sint ad dolore. Exercitation duis veniam velit occaecat est irure quis labore occaecat.\r\n",
    "registered": "2016-09-19T10:00:38 -09:00"
}
]
```

I'd like to create a new array only containing `id`, `name` and `age` from `arr`.

I tried to do it by using map() but I don't know how to use it well.
Is it possible to do it by using map() once or do I have to use another method in addition to map()?

Comment: _"I tried to do it by using map() "_ - please share this as a text-based [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
arr = [
{
    "_id": "6271fd40fe5c58d4cbd3a72f",
    "index": 0,
    "guid": "60f843d2-1b6b-4536-b421-e5df1c4ab735",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$2,534.11",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 27,
    "eyeColor": "brown",
    "name": "Miranda Nguyen",
    "gender": "male",
    "company": "ZENTIA",
    "email": "mirandanguyen@zentia.com",
    "phone": "+1 (833) 466-3207",
    "address": "198 Dank Court, Hartsville/Hartley, Indiana, 8416",
    "about": "Consectetur proident anim do commodo ipsum. Elit consectetur irure dolore voluptate. Enim aute voluptate et qui do. Eu pariatur laboris labore esse enim reprehenderit mollit ullamco fugiat. Laborum sunt veniam consectetur laboris cupidatat. Lorem tempor occaecat labore ut et eiusmod amet.\r\n",
    "registered": "2021-06-16T11:50:54 -09:00"
},
{
    "_id": "6271fd40e30856d15651c60c",
    "index": 1,
    "guid": "ee647592-0647-4ad5-96b1-eb6c06a32dbd",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$2,636.22",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 35,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "name": "Florence Flynn",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "ELENTRIX",
    "email": "florenceflynn@elentrix.com",
    "phone": "+1 (901) 525-3731",
    "address": "246 Billings Place, Brandermill, Guam, 5037",
    "about": "Sint non dolore cupidatat voluptate laboris adipisicing eu quis. Laboris nostrud qui dolor cillum dolor nulla sint culpa est reprehenderit sint ipsum nisi excepteur. Qui cupidatat sint do aliquip ut. Officia est aliquip fugiat ex enim do sunt consequat.\r\n",
    "registered": "2014-12-10T08:44:47 -09:00"
},
{
    "_id": "6271fd404394e16d79143873",
    "index": 2,
    "guid": "3d3890ff-8241-4a2b-a361-789e0298817a",
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$1,047.32",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 25,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": "Debbie Pratt",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "OPTIQUE",
    "email": "debbiepratt@optique.com",
    "phone": "+1 (831) 537-3188",
    "address": "737 Quentin Street, Calpine, Louisiana, 9102",
    "about": "Officia nisi labore mollit cupidatat exercitation commodo duis adipisicing officia amet laborum. Nulla qui commodo aliqua reprehenderit dolore cupidatat esse ea pariatur sint ad dolore. Exercitation duis veniam velit occaecat est irure quis labore occaecat.\r\n",
    "registered": "2016-09-19T10:00:38 -09:00"
}
]

// long hand
let result = arr.map(function(obj) {
  return {
    _id: obj._id,
    name: obj.name,
    age: obj.age
  }
})

console.log(result)



// shorthand, requires support for object destructuring, arrow functions
result = arr.map(({ _id, name, age }) => ({ _id, name, age }))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple ways to do it.

[Here is the documentation of map .](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

you can implement like this the map  method:

```
const yourNewArray = arr.map((item)=>{
  return {
     id:item._id,
     name:item.name,
     age:item.age
   }
})
```

> You can make this with every loop, but the pros of using a map here are
> because the map returns always the element if you want to implement
> with normal for loop or forEach loop, you will have to add each
> element in the array with `.push`

In case you want to return just some values from the array then you have the `.filter()` method

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```js
const arr = [
{
    "_id": "6271fd40fe5c58d4cbd3a72f",
    "index": 0,
    "guid": "60f843d2-1b6b-4536-b421-e5df1c4ab735",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$2,534.11",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 27,
    "eyeColor": "brown",
    "name": "Miranda Nguyen",
    "gender": "male",
    "company": "ZENTIA",
    "email": "mirandanguyen@zentia.com",
    "phone": "+1 (833) 466-3207",
    "address": "198 Dank Court, Hartsville/Hartley, Indiana, 8416",
    "about": "Consectetur proident anim do commodo ipsum. Elit consectetur irure dolore voluptate. Enim aute voluptate et qui do. Eu pariatur laboris labore esse enim reprehenderit mollit ullamco fugiat. Laborum sunt veniam consectetur laboris cupidatat. Lorem tempor occaecat labore ut et eiusmod amet.\r\n",
    "registered": "2021-06-16T11:50:54 -09:00"
},
{
    "_id": "6271fd40e30856d15651c60c",
    "index": 1,
    "guid": "ee647592-0647-4ad5-96b1-eb6c06a32dbd",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$2,636.22",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 35,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "name": "Florence Flynn",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "ELENTRIX",
    "email": "florenceflynn@elentrix.com",
    "phone": "+1 (901) 525-3731",
    "address": "246 Billings Place, Brandermill, Guam, 5037",
    "about": "Sint non dolore cupidatat voluptate laboris adipisicing eu quis. Laboris nostrud qui dolor cillum dolor nulla sint culpa est reprehenderit sint ipsum nisi excepteur. Qui cupidatat sint do aliquip ut. Officia est aliquip fugiat ex enim do sunt consequat.\r\n",
    "registered": "2014-12-10T08:44:47 -09:00"
},
{
    "_id": "6271fd404394e16d79143873",
    "index": 2,
    "guid": "3d3890ff-8241-4a2b-a361-789e0298817a",
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$1,047.32",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 25,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": "Debbie Pratt",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "OPTIQUE",
    "email": "debbiepratt@optique.com",
    "phone": "+1 (831) 537-3188",
    "address": "737 Quentin Street, Calpine, Louisiana, 9102",
    "about": "Officia nisi labore mollit cupidatat exercitation commodo duis adipisicing officia amet laborum. Nulla qui commodo aliqua reprehenderit dolore cupidatat esse ea pariatur sint ad dolore. Exercitation duis veniam velit occaecat est irure quis labore occaecat.\r\n",
    "registered": "2016-09-19T10:00:38 -09:00"
}
]

const result = arr.map(({_id, name, age}) => ({_id, name, age}))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const arr = [{_id: '6271fd40fe5c58d4cbd3a72f',index: 0,guid: '60f843d2-1b6b-4536-b421-e5df1c4ab735',isActive: true,balance: '$2,534.11',picture: 'http://placehold.it/32x32',age: 27,eyeColor: 'brown',name: 'Miranda Nguyen',gender: 'male',company: 'ZENTIA',email: 'mirandanguyen@zentia.com',phone: '+1 (833) 466-3207',address: '198 Dank Court, Hartsville/Hartley, Indiana, 8416',about: 'Consectetur proident anim do commodo ipsum. Elit consectetur irure dolore voluptate. Enim aute voluptate et qui do. Eu pariatur laboris labore esse enim reprehenderit mollit ullamco fugiat. Laborum sunt veniam consectetur laboris cupidatat. Lorem tempor occaecat labore ut et eiusmod amet.\r\n',registered: '2021-06-16T11:50:54 -09:00',},{_id: '6271fd40e30856d15651c60c',index: 1,guid: 'ee647592-0647-4ad5-96b1-eb6c06a32dbd',isActive: true,balance: '$2,636.22',picture: 'http://placehold.it/32x32',age: 35,eyeColor: 'blue',name: 'Florence Flynn',gender: 'female',company: 'ELENTRIX',email: 'florenceflynn@elentrix.com',phone: '+1 (901) 525-3731',address: '246 Billings Place, Brandermill, Guam, 5037',about: 'Sint non dolore cupidatat voluptate laboris adipisicing eu quis. Laboris nostrud qui dolor cillum dolor nulla sint culpa est reprehenderit sint ipsum nisi excepteur. Qui cupidatat sint do aliquip ut. Officia est aliquip fugiat ex enim do sunt consequat.\r\n',registered: '2014-12-10T08:44:47 -09:00',},{_id: '6271fd404394e16d79143873',index: 2,guid: '3d3890ff-8241-4a2b-a361-789e0298817a',isActive: false,balance: '$1,047.32',picture: 'http://placehold.it/32x32',age: 25,eyeColor: 'green',name: 'Debbie Pratt',gender: 'female',company: 'OPTIQUE',email: 'debbiepratt@optique.com',phone: '+1 (831) 537-3188',address: '737 Quentin Street, Calpine, Louisiana, 9102',about: 'Officia nisi labore mollit cupidatat exercitation commodo duis adipisicing officia amet laborum. Nulla qui commodo aliqua reprehenderit dolore cupidatat esse ea pariatur sint ad dolore. Exercitation duis veniam velit occaecat est irure quis labore occaecat.\r\n',registered: '2016-09-19T10:00:38 -09:00',},]

const result = arr.map(({ _id, name, age }) => ({ id: _id, name, age }))
console.log(result)
```